# Allowing non-existence on a filtered term in ElasticSearch with tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a boolean field that I'm trying to filter by, but I want to fetch documents that either have a specific value for this field, or doesn't have this field populated at all. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of dealing with it. First of all, you can use `null_value` attribute in the [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types.html) to specify how null value should be indexed. Alternatively, you can use [`exists`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/exists-filter.html) or [`missing`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter.html) filters along with [`bool`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter.html) or [`or`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/or-filter.html) filters to augment your query.